# Is there a way to redirect to another Action class without using on struts.xml

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, struts2

I have many classes created in my Struts application. I did not check whether logged in condition in any of the classes. Instead I have extended a base action class.

Now I want to create a pre-handler in my base action to check logged in and redirect if they are not logged in.

**I want something like this:**

```
public BaseAction(){
  if(isLoggedIn){
    //go to child which was called
   }
   else {   //redirect to login page
  }          
}
```

Another way is to check `isLoggedIn()` by calling this method in all action classes and defining a global result like

```
<result name="not-logged-in" type="redirectAction">Login.action</result>
```

Please help me to find better way for this.

Comment: You need to specify what version of Struts you're using, because your code has both Struts 1 and Struts 2 artifacts in it.

Comment: @DaveNewton OP tagged it Struts 2, but I re-tagged it Struts.

Comment: Thanks guys. Its struts2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to check in the constructor of the base action class, but you are mistaken. The constructor is used by the object factory to instantiate your action instance. In this stage a few things is available to you. In your case it's wrong. Another approach is if you move the logic into the method say `execute()` and call `super.execute()` before any method call would work, but if you forget to put the super call in the action then you may end up the action code running not authenticated. To prevent it you should run the code before any action is executed and be able to access the action instance or action context to be more Struts2. I guess you've never read the book [Struts 2 in Action](https://books.google.com.ua/books/about/STRUTS_2_IN_ACTION.html?id=1rbeG3-jdnoC) so I will give you some my own thoughts. It's about creating `AuthenticationInterceptor` and the action that implements `UserAware` that injects the user logged in into the action that implement this interface. The interceptor is looks like

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

public void destroy() {
}

public void init() {
}

public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
    Map session = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
    User user = (User) session.get(Struts2MyConstants.USER);
            
    if (user == null) {
        return Action.LOGIN; //login required result
    }               
    else {              
        Action action = (Action)actionInvocation.getAction();
        
        if (action instanceof UserAware) {
            User freshUser = myService.getUser(user.getId());
            ((UserAware)action).setUser(freshUser);
        }
        
        System.out.println("Logged in: interceptor");
        return actionInvocation.invoke();
    }
}
```

The `UserAware` is looks like

```
public interface UserAware {
    
    public void setUser( User user );
    
}
```

and make a secure default stack that will reference any action

```
<interceptors>
  <interceptor name="authenticationInterceptor" class="org.yourapp.struts.interceptor.AuthenticationInterceptor"/>
  <interceptor-stack name="secureStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="authenticationInterceptor"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
  </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
<default-interceptor-ref name="secureStack"/>
```

If you make your base action to implement `UserAware` then the user object that is logged in will be available not only from session but in action too if you define getter for the user or make it protected. You have to make the `User` object immutable so that not compromise the security feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`Filter`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html). It will be a lot more transparent than requiring all your classes to extend your `BaseAction`.

**Edit**

You would map this filter in your web.xml file, so it would be executed *before* the Struts controller servlet.

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>my.company.AuthorizationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mappging>
    <filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>StrutsActionServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Or by URL pattern:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Edit**

You have changed the question, and it appears it's struts 2 you're using after all. In that case, you can write an interceptor instead of a filter. It would basically do the same, but an interceptor can be configured along with the rest of your struts configuration.

Comment: Sorry. I just posted the way I analysed while browsing. But i want something like this in baseclass. I cant change all my action classes to check login.

Comment: That's the whole idea with filters. You're _not_ doing it in your action classes. A filter intercepts the request and does something _before_ your actions are executed. Your actions need no knowledge of this at all.

Comment: Anyways its an alternate solution for me. But what should class StrutsActionServlet return. How will the action class redirect to my login page?

Comment: That was just an example mapping. Your filter would do `response.sendRedirect()` to redirect to your login page. Struts is not involved at all.

Comment: It appears you're using Struts 2 after all, so I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I used Interceptor like this http://www.2bloggers.com/2010/12/struts-2-with-login-interceptor.html