# The validation concept understanding in Struts 2

Tags: java, validation, authentication, struts2, concept

I don't understand conception of Struts2 validation in next case :

My application consists of 2 actions:

1. login.action
2. drive.action

I can run `drive.action` from browser command line without filling user and password in `login.action`

How can I implement validation code which prevents the run of `drive.action` from command line if user hasn't successfully filled user and password in `login.action`?

Comment: Command line? Validation depends on the interceptors.

Comment: You are probably looking for authentication not validation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509606/sessions-in-struts2-application/5517526#5517526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## [The validation concept](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation.html)
>
> Struts 2 validation is configured via XML or annotations. Manual
> validation in the action is also possible, and may be combined with
> XML and annotation-driven validation.
>
> Validation also depends on both the validation and workflow
> interceptors (both are included in the default interceptor stack). The
> validation interceptor does the validation itself and creates a list
> of field-specific errors. The workflow interceptor checks for the
> presence of validation errors: if any are found, it returns the
> "input" result (by default), taking the user back to the form which
> contained the validation errors.
>
> If we're using the default settings and our action doesn't have an
> "input" result defined and there are validation (or, incidentally,
> type conversion) errors, we'll get an error message back telling us
> there's no "input" result defined for the action.

---

It is simple, you map the validators to the fields via the validation configuration file, or via annotations. Then apply a [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html) to the action via referencing it explicitly or implicitly via the interceptor stack, custom stack or [`defaultStack`](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/introducing-interceptors.html#introducing-interceptors-1).

When validation started it invokes the validation manager to perform actual validation and save errors to the [`ValidationAware`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ValidationAware.html) action.

Your action should implement this interface, or just extend the [`ActionSupport`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html) where it's already implemented, to save the errors. Then [`workflow` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/default-workflow-interceptor.html) checks for those errors and if found any of them redirect to the [`INPUT`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/Action.html#INPUT) result, if no errors found the action invocation is executed. You may also add a *programmatic* validation to the action by implementing [`Validateable`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/Validateable.html) interface, which [`ActionSupport`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html) is implemented by default, hence to override the [`validate()`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html#validate--) method(s).

As a supplement to XML based validation you could also apply annotation based configuration. This only the server-side validation, the client-side validation applied to the browser enabled javascript via Struts tags used for rendering a validation content to the page being validated.

All of this concept is not applicable to the action which requires authentication (unless the authentication interceptor is applied to the action). If you use JAAS authentication, then you should consider your action to implement [`PrincipalAware`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/PrincipalAware.html) or use `roles` interceptor to restrict access to the action which checks the [`isUserInRole()`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/PrincipalProxy.html#isUserInRole-java.lang.String-). You may use [`Action.LOGIN`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/Action.html#LOGIN) result to return to the login page in authentication interceptor if the user is not authenticated like in [Is there a way to redirect to another action class without using on `struts.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254934/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-to-another-action-class-without-using-on-struts-xml/16256030#16256030) example.

Comment: If i enable client side validation then will the server side validation disabled?@ Roman C

Comment: @tanmoy No, the server side validation works regardless of client-side validation.

Comment: @ Roman C So we don't need separate javascript code for validation. Am i correct?

Comment: You can use S2 inbuilt javascript code or use a custom code it depends on requirements.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to use interceptor as said by Dave Newton.
Interceptor code is :

```
package com.interceptor;
public class SessionInterceptor implements Interceptor,ServletRequestAware,SessionAware
{ 
   HttpServletRequest request; //request object
   public Map<String, Object> sessionMap;

@Override
public void setSession(Map<String, Object> arg0) {
    
    this.sessionMap = arg0;
}

@Override
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest arg0) {
    
    this.request = arg0;
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    
    
}

@Override
public void init() {
    
    
}

@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    
    sessionMap=invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
    ActionContext context=(ActionContext)invocation.getInvocationContext();

    String className = invocation.getAction().getClass().getName();
    String ActionName = invocation.getAction().toString();//action name which is called
           
            //below check if session map or username is null or you logic
            if(sessionMap==null || sessionMap.get("userName")==null){
            return "loginError";    //this will return without calling your drive.action if user name or session is null
        }else{
            return invocation.invoke();  //if session is available or user name then it will run the action
        }
  }//end of intercept method
}//end of class
```

struts.xml is :

```
    <package name="Pkg" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="sessionCheck" class="com.interceptor.SessionInterceptor">
    </interceptor>
    <interceptor-stack name="sessionStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="sessionCheck"/>          
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
    
    <default-interceptor-ref name="sessionStack"></default-interceptor-ref>
    
    <global-results>
        <result name="loginError">login.jsp</result>
    </global-results>
           //here all the actions which you want to apply interceptor
         //rest of actions where above SessionInterceptor will be applied
        ...
        ....
        .....
```

Do not write you first login.action inside above package instead create new package in `struts.xml` like :

```
   <package name="Pkg2" extends="struts-default">       
    <action name="login.action" class="com.action.LogAction" method="execute">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">drive</result> <!-- here action name drive is action from above package where interceptor is applied or any which you want-->
    </action>
  </package>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.
Here are few links which may help you

1. [session interceptor](http://www.jkstack.com/2013/01/session-management-using-login.html)
2. [package configuration](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/package-configuration.html)
3. [interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/interceptors.html)
4. [interceptor stack example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-interceptor-stack-example/)

Comment: Your interceptor isn't going to work. The SessionAware and ServletRequestAware interfaces mark _actions_ for injection, not other _interceptors_. Revise it to get the session and request off of the invocation context.

Comment: @StevenBenitez:Sir, above code is working for me. If there are mistakes then please do correct.

Comment: I'm not sure how it would be working. What is injecting the session map and the HttpServletRequest? Normally, the ServletConfigInterceptor injects those into _actions_. Interceptors don't intercept other _interceptors_, so again, not sure how this is working.