# Struts2 keep same action url if validation fail using struts2-bean-validation-plugin

Tags: struts2, bean-validation, struts2-interceptors

I am using Struts 2 and I have two action one will show the register form and second will be register user.

I want to achieve is while submitting form if any validation fail then user will be redirect to previous page with errors details.

I have use struts2-bean-validation-plugin for validating user bean.

My configuration files are as below

### struts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
    
        <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="beanValidation" class="org.apache.struts.beanvalidation.validation.interceptor.BeanValidationInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-stack name="appDefaultStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="beanValidation"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>

        <action name="userRegisterForm" method="userRegisterForm" class="com.pc.collabtest.actions.UserRegisterAction">
            <result name="success">/userRegisterForm.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="userRegister" method="userRegister" class="com.pc.collabtest.actions.UserRegisterAction" >
             <interceptor-ref name="appDefaultStack"/>
            <result name="userList" type="redirectAction">userList</result>
            <result name="userRegisterForm" type="redirectAction">userRegisterForm</result>
            <result name="input" type="redirectAction">userRegisterForm</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

### And Action class is

```java
package com.pc.collabtest.actions;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.pc.collabtest.model.User;
import com.pc.collabtest.service.UserService;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class UserRegisterAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Valid
    public User user;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;    
    
    public String userRegisterForm() throws Exception {
        return "success";
    }

    public String userRegister() throws Exception {
        if (user != null) {
            if(userService.saveUser(user) != null) {
                return "userList";
            }
        }
        return "userRegisterForm";
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

Comment: What prevents you to achieve desired? If you have validation errors then then store them to the validation context and redirect to the error page. If you need more understanding how validation is working read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18504177/573032).

Comment: Actually I have used struts2-bean-validation-plugin and all that validation doing by that plugin, when ever that form has error it return "input" as a result so based on that result I can show jsp or redirect action, if I do redirect then all validation error has been remove because it will create new request object. and if I show same jsp form then it will show the errors but  url will not be change.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I need some configuration changes in **struts.xml** file you can see I have create two package as I don't need validation in every action i.e showing registration form doesn't need any validation where submit registration form needed. so I put u **userRegister** action in **struts-bean-validation** package. and whenever **userRegister**(submit) action return **input** result because of validation fail we will redirect **userRegisterForm** to show registration form but at this point struts will create new request object so we will loose error result so for that we use struts default interceptor **store** with operation mode **STORE** which will store error result in **session** and in **userRegisterForm** action again we use **store** interceptor but with operation mode **RETRIEVE** so that struts will fetch error result from session.

**Note** here you can see I use **beanValidationDefaultStack** interceptor which is mention in **struts2-bean-validation-plugin.jar** struts-plugin.xml file. because what I assume if we use interceptor then struts will now use default interceptor.

````xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="userRegisterForm" method="userRegisterForm" class="com.pc.collabtest.actions.UserRegisterAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="store"><param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="success">/userRegisterForm.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

    <package name="my-bean-validation" extends="struts-bean-validation">
        <action name="userRegister" method="userRegister" class="com.pc.collabtest.actions.UserRegisterAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="store"><param name="operationMode">STORE</param></interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="beanValidationDefaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="userList" type="redirectAction">userList</result>
            <result name="userRegisterForm" type="redirectAction">userRegisterForm</result>
            <result name="input" type="redirectAction">userRegisterForm</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts> ```
````