# How to check if user is logged in with Struts 2

Tags: java, authentication, session, struts2, httpsession

I'm not able to manage a session with Struts2 .

If I login successfully and if I click the URL of login again, it again asks for login.

I want it to be *logged in* untill timeout doesn't happens.

Comment: How exactly are you maintaining sessions ?

Answer (score 0):

The session is already managed in Struts2.

If you want to put some object like an user to the session you can use authentication interceptor like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16256030/573032).

It checks if an user in session and let the action invoke, otherwise it returns a `login` result.

The user might want to login several times under different accounts, so you should not restrict him/her from doing it.

In the JSP you could check the user in session with the `if` tag using a `#session` context variable.

```
<s:if test="#session.user == null">
 <s:a action="login"><s:text name="label.enter"/></s:a>
</s:if>
<s:else>
  <s:a action="logout"><s:text name="label.exit"/></s:a>
</s:else>
```