# How to save login credentials to shared preferences after successful login to web service[Struts2]

Tags: java, android, struts2

I have gone thorugh no. of posts about shared preferences and web services in android but none of them is explaining about - how to save login credential after successful login to any web service (Mine is based on struts2 framework).

Any suggestion will be much helpful to me ..

M using [AyncTask] mechanism  to send login credentials to web service for authentication but don't know how to handle the response and work with sharedPrefrences simultaneously..

Comment: Working with an HTTP response and shared preferences "siimultaneously" is the same as working with them separately; what's the specific issue?

Comment: @dave problem is that -- in first step my application authenticate user's login credentials from j2ee web service--> if its successful (checking from http response)  then i need to open another activity with logged-in user's detail but at this time i want to store these credentials in sharedpreferences also . In addition , when next time user open my app then he need not to login again.  ...     I am beginner in Android . :)

Comment: @HarpreetSandhu-TheCoder How did you handle authentication, may be you need to write the authentication interceptor like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16256030/573032)?

Comment: @RomanC i know Interceptor . but here i am not using them because after first successful authentication by web service i want to store authentication data(like token or login credentials) in sharedPreferences .. I want to make my app as GMail etc because these app stores credentials in sharedPreferences and don't ask user to fill username ,password again and again .

Comment: yes, that's why you need it :)

Comment: yeah @RomanC . thnx you got my point :)