# How to execute a method before execution of any action (check if a user has logged in) Struts 2

Tags: java, authentication, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I want to check if the (session) user has logged in
so if a user tried to reach a resource (a link) and he's not connected he
must be redirected to login page, I could this verification

```
//when logging in
sessionMap.put("logined",true);
```

then

```
public String checkLogin() {
//when trying to reach a resource
if ((Boolean) sessionMap.get("logined")) return "Logined";
    else return "notLogined";
}
```

but I must execute this method in every method-action in class action
and I must treat the result in every action on `struts.xml`.

so, my question is if there is a "light" solution using `SessionAware` and `sessionMap`:

```
    private SessionMap<String,Object> sessionMap;
```

I rather *not using* Spring Security.

Comment: Google for "servlet filter", or just read the javadoc of ServletFilter.

Comment: Interceptors. And you should really consider to use some security framework.

Comment: I'm working on a servlet filter now as Nizet suggested, but can you suggest some simple security framework ?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute your method in the `prepare()`. To use this feature your action class should implement `Preparable` interface. Assumed that actions are configured to use `defaultStack` of interceptors which include this feature.

> [**Prepare Interceptor:**](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/prepare-interceptor.html)
>
> This interceptor calls `prepare()` on actions which implement `Preparable`. This interceptor is very useful for any situation where you need to ensure some logic runs before the actual execute method runs.

---

If your logic is beyond the scope of the action class, then consider to use a custom interceptor for authentication. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16256030/573032) is an example of authentication interceptor.