# Using <s:if> tag to check if the user is in session in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I'd like to know if it's possible to check with the `<s:if>` tag of Struts 2 if the user is in session.

If the user is in session, I need it to be shown `Logout` otherwise `Login`.

I use the interface `SessionAware` for login action and this class `User`.

```
package it.pwm.wynd.pojo.user;


public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer idUser;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name, String username, String password, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getIdUser() {
        return this.idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(Integer idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Accessing session variables is covered in the [Struts 2 Tags documentation tree](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/) in multiple places, but it might be best to take a quick step back and review the [OGNL overview](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl).

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 tags cannot work without associated filer. If you use Struts tags in JSP make sure you read first about [tags](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers).

The session map can be injected into the action if it is `SessionAware`.

> If you want to put some object like an `user` to the session you can use authentication interceptor like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16256030/573032).
>
> It checks if an `user` in session and let the action invoke, otherwise it returns a `login` result.
>
> The user might want to login several times under different accounts, so you should not restrict him/her from doing it.

In the JSP you could check the `user` in session with the [`<s:if>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/if-tag.html) using a `#session` context variable.

```xhtml
<s:if test="#session.user == null">
 <s:a action="login">Login</s:a>
</s:if>
<s:else>
  <s:a action="logout">Logout</s:a>
</s:else>
```